# Is there any diferences between UIWebview and mobile Safari in rendering pages?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, uiwebview

I was complained by my boss about the low rendering performance. What is the difference between App using UIWebView and Safari when rendering the same page?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the OS version? I remember Apple reduced JS Engine performance by 25% inside webviewUI during iOS7 release. Later they increased it, but not sure how it is performing now. Have not checked in a while

Comment: Now I'm using iOS 10.2 , is this issue counts?

Answer (score 4):

UIWebView is deprecated.

From Apple Docs.

> Important
>
> Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content
> to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView.

@import WebKit
And use WKWebView

WKWebView has much improved JS implementation and use.
It is very similar in performance to Safari.

Differences: WKWebView can be used as a view of your apps controller. Safari runs as a separate app. SafariController runs Safari in its own ViewController within your app.

Comment: Meant to say "SafariController runs Safari in it's own viewController within your app."

Comment: But WKWebView makes requests and renders content out-of-process, meaning my app does not hear the requests they make. So I can't use WKWebview to observe JS Loading If I want do sth when JS finished.Any other alternative?

Comment: WKWebView has evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler: and WKScriptMessageHandler for evaluating JS and getting messages from JS. It also has WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate for observing the loading progress and performing actions based on content and 3D touch. You can even inject JS into the page at the top or bottom using WKUserScript. Not sure what else you could want. So for example, not only do you have the WKUINavigation to know when the loading is finished, you could use WKUserScript to inject JS at the end which sends your script handler a message when it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes there are some difference and similarity in Mobile Safari and UIWebview**

- UIWebView support all HTML5 features like Mobile Safari
- UIWebView is a bit more strict than Safari on certain features. Example: when setting a width/height style through JS, you need to add 'px' behind the number, while Mobile Safari does not require that.
- For authentication, UIWebView does not handle authentication challenges automatically, it's up to the developers to handle them.
- UIWebView does not have the Nitro Javascript engine, so it executes
  JS slower than Mobile Safari.
- UIWebView does not keep track of the browsing history for page transitions within frames, which may be a desirable feature.

Hope this answer helps you out

Comment: So is there any possibility that UIWebview in my app run same page as fast as Safari in mobile?

Comment: you can import webkit and optimize it as per your need,